# What is a good SharePoint 2007 anti-virus solution?

Tags: sharepoint, anti-virus

What real-world experiences have you had with SharePoint anti-virus products? Are there any that should be avoided? So far I have had [Microsoft Forefront](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/serversecurity/sharepoint/en/us/default.aspx) recommended but that's it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consider merging with http://serverfault.com/questions/4150/is-it-important-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-specific-anti-virus-solution ?

Comment: Wasn't sure as they are two different questions... Will see based on other feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anti-Virus is a commodity product, and they all have the same capabilities -- it's a cost-based decision.

Look at the top vendors (Symantec, McAfee, Sophos, Trend, Kapersky, Microsoft, etc), haggle aggressively, then do it again in a couple of years. McAfee will try to tell you that if you buy all McAfee stuff, ePO will lower your TCO. That may or may not be true for you. If you have an ELA, Microsoft will be very aggressive in pricing for their offerings.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter. Forefront includes 5 anti-virus engines including some that you've mentioned so maybe I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

All the SharePoint MVPs seem to recommend Forefront because of the different engines that come with it and because of the overheads that come with all the other products.

They do this NOT because it is from Microsoft (just in case that wasn't clear).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Symantec Antivirus Enterprise edition. Constantly up to date, consumes very little resources, and decently priced.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your farm setup. However, I've worked with several clients and the most used AntiVirus solutions for SharePoint are:

- McAfee PortalShield for Microsoft SharePoint
- Symantec Protection for SharePoint Servers
- TrenMicro Portal Protect

These are in no particular order.